# Text comparison rules on node:body:value with input filters

Tags: rules, input-formats

My text comparison rule works like a charm if the user selects 'Plain text'.  If they use 'Filtered HTML' it doesn't find a match even though the pattern does exist in the raw and filtered versions of the text.

The short question is how can a text comparison rule be run against filtered input?

The long version is what's the process by which rules and input filters interact and why is this an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case a custom input format was replacing youtube links with an iframe embedded video. Everything inside the iframe wasn't matching. My solution was to add the original youtube link outside of the iframe tag replacement pattern.

But why? Hypothesis is that one of the filters ends up running the body through htmlspecialchars.